# How to add fixed text

Tags: aframe

This question is specific to aframe library.

I was wondering how you can make a text always fixed on the screen, no matter how users move/look around;

E.g. I am developing an aframe VR game and I want to show the scores on the top left of the screen. So no matter what angle the user looks at or wherever he moves to, he will be able to see the his score on the screen.

Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Hi, I think if you add the text as a child of the camera (like the cursor example https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/cursor.md) it will always be in the users view because the cursor always is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the text a child of the camera:

```
<a-camera>
 <a-text value="Hello, World!" position="0 0 -1"></a-text>
</a-camera>
```

This will place the text 1m in front of the user.

Comment: it's a little hard to adjust the position so they appear consistently on PC and mobile view though; Like if it's top left on PC view, it's not viewable on mobile; any suggestions except for putting it in the middle?